# Partition system to find a matching element with bitwise comparisons

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, partitioning

I have a large list of 64 bit numbers (several millions).

I need to find, given an input number, the best x matches in the list.

The score given to a comparison is the number of bits the input value and the compared value have in common.

I can trade accuracy for speed.

Is there any partitioning system that would allow me to not scan the whole list?

---

Here is more information, in answer to the comments:

The list of numbers can be sorted, it rarely changes and it is possible to sort it offline.

When I said I can trade accuracy for speed, I mean that speed is very important and it would be acceptable to have 25% results of quality and have 75% of results that could have maybe better matches but are still relevant.

Comment: Just to make sure: we assume that the list is not sorted in any way and that sorting it beforehand is undesirable?

Comment: If we have sorting: What about an approach that assumes the list is ordered by the number of `0`s (of the binary rep of numbers in the list). You know the number of `0`s in your input number and therefore can decide in which half you want to continue your search. And then repeat.

Comment: Is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.2982.pdf useful?  It shows how to use precomputation to prepare hash tables (for various substrings of bits in the values) that then enable the search to be performed quickly.  This will only be useful if the list is fixed and you want to perform many matches (otherwise the precomputation will be too costly).

Comment: Trade accuracy for speed?

Comment: I have added more details in the main post.